# Nvidia Geforce 6150 Multiple Monitors Dualview Issue on HP Pavilion tx2001au

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a Nvidia Geforce 6150 card on my Laptop - [HP Pavilion tx2001au Entertainment Notebook PC](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?lc=en&dlc=&cc=us&lang=&product=3653674&)  . I attached a LCD monitor to my Laptop..I am not getting display on second monitor in dualview mode (extended desktop) .However,on Clone Display mode i get display on both the laptop monitor and the external display. Whats the issue ?

OS : Windows Vista Home Premium 32 bit
Nvidia Driver : 7.15.11.5682   [link](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=ob-56996-1&lc=en&dlc=&cc=us&lang=&os=2093&product=3653674)

I've checked the steps mentioned [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01369231&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&product=3653674) ..but in the Display Settings, the laptop shows one monitor even after connecting the external display.is this a known issue with the NVIDIA driver for Geforce 6150 ?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, get a recent driver. You should only use vendor provided drivers when you are using a customized VGA system. Like Lenovo's ATI+Intel solution or the ASUS hybrid SLI solution.

Download/install the recent drivers: http://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/win7_winvista_32bit_191.07_whql_uk.html

Then report back with the result.

Comment: The OEM provided driver is already installed. The link you have doesn't show Geforce 6150 Go as a  supported product.

Comment: The OEM provided driver is often outdate. And there is no 'special driver' for "6150 Go". The driver should work for all 6xxx cards. Just try it. If it won't work, you can easily uninstall it from Vista. (But before you install it, remove the vendor given one, and do a reboot).

Comment: The latest 191.07 GeForce/ION Driver installer says that it cannot find any compatible hardware

Comment: And thats what you get when you choose your VGA? Try the "Archived and beta drivers" part. There you'll find some other ones also. Use 1 version older. (If I remember clearly, the 177.xx series is the latest before the 'latest&greatest' one).

ps.: Sorry for the late answer, didnt get a reply in email that I got a comment.